# Is it OK to flag own question/answer for English grammar moderation?

Tags: discussion, moderation, english, grammatical-correction

I'm Russian speaking, and English is my second language, which isn't perfect. So, when I'm posting questions or/and answers in English, I probably make grammar mistakes, or my sentences might not be very clear.

Is it OK to ask moderation (with a flag) for help with improving English grammar in my own posts?

Comment: No, I wouldn't raise a flag for that. Perhaps ask a colleague or friend to proof read your post. Your english in this post doesn't seem too bad.

Comment: As a french guy, I understand your struggle.

Comment: Note that there is a Russian Stack Overflow: [ru.so]...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yes, I registered on both. Thank you.

Comment: I guess you could add a note asking for someone to check & improve your English, either at the end of your post, or as a comment. The community will generally correct minor mistakes (or point out typos via a comment), but people tend to avoid correcting grammar if it's mostly ok, or if it's so bad that it's unreadable, so explicitly asking for help with your English may encourage them. But I agree with Nathan that it's probably better to ask for help in a chat room if you don't have a friend or colleague who can help you.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> Is it OK to ask moderation (with flag) help with improving English gramma in own posts?

No, moderator flags should only be used for things that regular users cannot handle.

You do have a couple options though.  If you can find a chat room willing to help you out then you can post a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) with the content and they can help you out editing it until it is ready to post.

Another option is to just post it with your best effort and let the community fix up any minor grammar/spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 22):

No, it's not appropriate to flag your posts for moderator attention because of their grammatical errors.

Community members may choose to edit the post, if they want to.  Moderators are there to handle issues that cannot be resolved by the community, and a few grammatical errors doesn't qualify.