# Is it OK to ask for edits on my own posts to fix English?

Tags: support, edits, english

English is not my first language. I think that's pretty obvious for anybody reading one of my posts here. I am trying to improve my English, but it is a slow process.

The problem is, even given a lot of time and effort, my English skills remain fairly poor, and I know that I have a lot of mistakes in my posts. I don't feel so good about that.

Yesterday, I was trying to fix one of my meta posts, but was struggling too much, so I tried to make a [little edit with a summary asking for help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/351948/4). Stack Overflow being what it is, some minutes later, a good fellow [edited my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/351948/5) and fixed all of the English issues. Yay!

But I'm not sure whether editing all my posts with summary like "*guys help*" is a good thing. I've only done this once, and it worked out okay, but I don't think spamming edits like this is a good practice.

On the other hand, I would really like to have my biggest errors fixed—not only for the sake of others who read my posts, but also to improve my skills.

Is there a proper way to ask users to help me with English syntax in my posts? **Would it be OK to ask for edits on my own questions to fix my English? If yes, how should I do that?**

Comment: Your English seems fine, as long as it's somewhat understandable people won't mind. Depending on what tags your posting in you'll find someone will come along and edit it for you pretty quickly anyway (I do it all the time for the javascript tag)

Comment: Yes, editing your answer to include a request for edits isn't exactly productive. Neither is [flagging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352451/is-it-ok-to-flag-own-question-answer-for-english-grammar-moderation). The answer to the linked question recommends finding a chat room.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with George—the English in this question wasn't bad at all. I want to say that, because if you look at my edit, it probably looks like *oh my god, everything was wrong!*, but that's not the case. Most of what I changed was stylistic stuff, just to make it read better. What you had was neither wrong nor unclear; it just wasn't perfectly idiomatic. The only thing you had that was really wrong was "it rise slowly". Not only should "rise" have been plural, but "rise" just doesn't make sense in that context. Oh, and also English is a proper noun, so it's capitalized.

Comment: Your english is fine, better than that of some americans I know. Don't fuss about your english level.

Comment: For the record, I would have edited your post, exactly the same, regardless of your edit summary. I edit a _lot_. I just thought it was amusing to "reply" in my summary. (Also, as was already said above, the needed improvements were very minor, so don't worry too much!)

Comment: CodyGray & JoshCaswell: I don't like to be this kind of "thank you sooo muuchhh guys xoxo" people, but thanks _soooo muuuchh_ for your edits - it helps a lot. Well, ok, my english is fair - I will try to not being _too much_ focused on it so.

Answer (score 12):

> Is that ok to ask for edit on my own questions to fix my english? If yes, how should I do that?

No. Stuff like that is just noise. Questions should include only *relevant* information, not meta-commentary and procedural requests.

Stack Overflow is collaboratively edited, so it is ***assumed*** that you want other users to fix your English mistakes (or, indeed, any other obvious mistakes). You don't need to specify what is already assumed.

If one of your posts is difficult to read, and someone who has time comes across it, then they will edit it. If not, it'll sit unedited until such time as someone comes across it and is willing to edit it. We don't need another "queue" where "posts in need of grammar edits" <strike>rot</strike> wait. The editing process works best when editors come across it organically.

If you need or want *immediate* help on composing English syntax, then you could consider either asking for help in a topical chat room or asking a question on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com). (Obviously, if you ask a question on ELL, don't just dump in a link to your Stack Overflow post. Put the relevant bits in the question itself, just like you would code for a question you ask here!)

**See also:** [Advice for non-native English speakers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers)

Comment: I wasn't speaking to add this to my questions - but asking for help by edit's summary. But anyway, you made a point saying it's assumed that others people would fix it if needed.

Comment: I'm so old I remember when Cody wasn't a mod (just dropping this here for later)

Comment: I'm so old I remember when @Will *was* a mod... :'(